# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'arc' of undefined

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, d3.js, requirejs

I am new to D3 and badly stuck in this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'arc' of undefined` as I am not able to figure out why this error is coming, It doesn't come every time and I have no idea how to reproduce this one.

Using this one code `d3.arc().innerRadius(this.prop.innerRadius).outerRadius(this.prop.outerRadius)` to plot donut chart.

I have followed this [DOC](http://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/37e8d3ec0c5125e7e5dd) to configure d3 with requireJS

Here are my configuration details:

• Backbone JS (v1.3.3)

• Require JS (v2.3.3)

• D3 v4.4.0 & tried v5.7.0

• Using the donut chart in Cordova android app

• Android version-6.1.0

• Cordova-7.1.2

Comment: will you please show code i mean more detailed one?

Comment: Can you make a minimal script to replicate, on something like jsfiddle or just as a few lines of JavaScript with d3.js loaded? If you're going to mention all the platforms in your stack, you should at least make sure that the problem goes away entirely when you put it in a plain environment.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to access `d3` before the file is loaded. That might be why you're not able to reproduce the issue.

Try moving your code inside an onload function?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  d3.arc().innerRadius(this.prop.innerRadius).outerRadius(this.prop.outerRadius)
});
```

Or window.onload if you don't have jQuery